# admob remove click from my account?

Tags: admob

Admob delete clicks
 the problem from 3 days

I see the click "example" 5 clicks and after 10 minutes it's down to 1 click

Please help

Comment: Please add more details...

Comment: from 3 days my clicks down from 45 to 15 every 10 minutes I see my admob and I see the clicks down

Comment: I mean, add more details to your question(edit).